# Create image resource and get EXIF info without loading image twice

Tags: php, image, exif, imagecreatefromjpg

I have some PHP code which loads images and does some stuff to them. The images are large and slow to load (mounted SMB share), so I am trying to increase its efficiency.

I'm using [imagecreatefromjpeg](https://www.php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg) to load an image from a JPG, and [exif_read_data](https://www.php.net/exif_read_data) to get the EXIF data from that image.

If my understanding of the below code snippet is correct, this results in PHP having to load the image twice. It's possible Linux is caching the file in memory or something so this isn't an issue, I don't know... but I'd like to know if there is any way I can avoid loading the image from disk twice and still get both an image resource I can manipulate, and the EXIF data?

```php
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
$exif = exif_read_data($filename);

// do stuff to the image using the exif data
```

Comment: That does not appear to be correct:
code `$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename); $exif = exif_read_data($img);` results in `Warning:  exif_read_data(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource`

Comment: Oh yes, I checked that now. I misunderstood `stream resource` concept